# Conda hangs on solving environment when installing PySide2

Tags: python, conda, pyside2

This has been discussed before but I cannot find any way to get this working with fixes I've seen. Conda hangs on solving environment when installing pyside2 with the forge channel. I have tried removing and readding the channel, reinstalling anaconda, and uninstalling anaconda, and installing miniconda instead. The last one kind of worked, the package started to be installed but crashed midway through. I was able to start qt designer but I couldn't import the pyside2 package.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add more details about what happened when it "crashed midway through?"

Comment: Have you tried creating a new environment (`conda create -n foo -c conda-forge pyside2`)? Oftentimes, the Anaconda **base** environment has too many packages installed by default to readily (i.e., in reasonable amount of time) reconfigure to accommodate for new packages. This can be a motivating factor for migrating to Miniconda.

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately it did not work. Eventually I just used pyqt5